# GridView How to update a value of current editing row with a new one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

-Simple gridview and sql data source to bind the data info to gridview.

On row updating how can I update a certain cell of current editing row with a new value set by me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in visual studio you can use the graphical interface to change properities to both gridview and sql datasource and configure this without writing code.

Take a look at this if you want to see how it's done in asp:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand.aspx

What really happens is that it updates the whole row in database, and displays the new values. This means that you don't need to change value in just one cell, but rather the whole row

Comment: On row updating I want to change a value from a cell then replace it with the new one set by me but the only way is updating I think

Comment: because I can use sqldata source implemented option for updating but as I said I just want to replace from a certain cell of the current editing row the value with a new one everytime the update button is clicked .

Comment: you are correct, only way is updating. and there is functions for this in sqldatasource. There is really no point in creating a method for updating only one cell. The fact is that when updating one row, with one value changed, you end up with updating only one cell. Not the whole row.

Comment: I was not able to understand the sample you gave me

Comment: How far did you come, and what did you not understand?

Comment: Sorry but I coulnd't understand the code , not just that code but in general I don't understand design code , I'd prefer source coding. thank you .